# Deploying a Visual C++ program using InstallShield Limited

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to deploy a simple C++ Open GL graphics program using InstallShield Limited Edition. I have managed to create an example installer, but my main program crashes on start up. My debugger gave me a pretty vague error

```
  error_text    0x00cceb28 L"R6010\r\n- abort() has been called\r\n"    const wchar_t * const
```

in file crt0msg.c

I have run dependency walker and it says that I am missing the following:

```
   API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
   API-MS-WIN-CORE-PRIVATEPROFILE-L1-1-1.DLL
   API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
   API-MS-WIN-CORE-SHUTDOWN-L1-1-1.DLL
   EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-UICONTEXT-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
   IESHIMS.DLL
```

As far as I know these are windows systems .dlls? I cant seems to run the profiler as dependency walker always hangs and crashes. I have tested my example project and it seems to be missing the same .dll's but runs fine.

The project has 2 external libraries in the dependencies (Never built one with external libraries before). I have also included a folder with text files next to the Primary output as is the structure in the release folder of VS2013. The assets folder etc seem to be compiling.

I have never deployed a project before, could anyone let me know what might be the cause?

Comment: I would suggest you look into NSIS instead http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page Those library names do not tell me anything otherwise!

Comment: I am thinking the problem might be the text files. I use them as readfile('file/textfile'); So I have added it to the project manually as a folder under the main project output? Unfortunately I dont have time to learn to script NSIS this time as I need a running version asap and install shield is supposed to be automatic.

Comment: We just converted an installer from IS to NSIS for a client, after spending 2 or 3 days trying to make it work right. It took us one day (one person about 8h) to convert to IS. Unless you have very heavy scripting, you can use a .bat file to do whatever work IS is expected to do in its scripting language. Also we had some problems with updating the Registry, that was because we needed to run the installer as administrator under Win7 or Win8. The basics under NSIS are very similar: you select directories and say where you want them on the target. You can also select just one file at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to the assets folder not linking correctly. I am going to try a different installer however.